# Slow boot due to some IO wait

Tags: bootchart, boot-time

I would like to improve boot time of my system now it takes almost minute. The system boots from SSD. According to bootchart the system waits for something for at least 30 seconds and does almost nothing. The bootchart picure is below. I have two questions:

1. What causes this pause an how can I improve boot time?
2. Is there a better place place to ask such questions?

Ubuntu wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting encourages posting bootchart data but I see no way to get feedback on it there and askubuntu have several similar questions mostly unanswered:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/221971/why-is-my-system-slow-to-boot
- [How can I improve my boot time? (bootchart and dmesg output included)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243552/how-can-i-improve-my-boot-time-bootchart-and-dmesg-output-included)

[image: The bootchart]